# Can I have the same save directory for both Linux and Windows?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I've recently been using Linux a bit more, and have set up a symbolic link to my Feed the Beast folder in `%APPDATA%\feedthebeast` to the `/home/jeffreylin_/.feedthebeast` folder so that they are the same place. So now the settings are synchronized.

However, there is also the problem of the save data folder, which is different from the launcher settings location. When I select the Options tab of the FTB Launcher, the Launch Folder section says that it is at `D:\Games\Minecraft\Feed The Beast`, which works for Windows, but for Linux, that same directory is at `/media/Jeffrey/Games/Minecraft/Feed The Beast`. Neither Windows nor Linux recognizes the other's filesystem, and thus I have to manually change the install location every time.

While I realize that there may not be a way to make these two synonymous with one another, there should be *some* way to automate changing between them depending on what OS I'm in. Can this be accomplished?

Comment: Why is Linux not recognizing Windows fs? Though that's more suited for SU than arqade, but it may be easier to fix that (if both versions can share the save files ofc.)

Comment: Linux does recognize NTFS, but like I said, the folder hierarchy is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to have two separate launchers. By having one launcher on the Linux side and a different launcher on the Windows sides, the configuration files don't get mixed up. It is not possible to dynamically change the path in the `Launch Folder` option.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a separate partition on your hard drive, and store the files there. Not sure if this may change how linux is set up with FTB, but you will need to manage the settings separately. The saves, mods, and other Minecraft data will all be unified, however.